# Corrupted mpeg-4 files when trying to put recording and pulling screenrecord videos in script

Tags: bash, adb, screen-recording

I want to write a script that initiates `adb shell screenrecord` in the background of my looping script. The looping script will be waiting at a menu waiting to read a 1 character user input.

When user presses any key, I want to automatically stop the screen-recording and pull the video file onto the user's computer.

On top of that, I will need to be able to place a countdown timer that will display on screen once the screenrecording commences, so they know how close to the 3min limit they are;

..using `printf "\r%*s" ((0)) "$remainingTime"` in a `for` loop for example.

This is the general idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
fileName="rec.$$.mp4"

record(){
    adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/$fileName &

    read -n 1 -s -r -p ''

    #EOF represents where the screenrecord command expects the EOF signal
    EOF
}

extract(){
    adb pull sdcard/$fileName
}

record | wait && extract
exit
```

Using this method to interrupt the screenrecord (when replacing  EOF with either `return` or `kill "$childPID"`) may be the problem, but I cannot find anywhere how to accomplish the EOF interrupt to avoid corrupting the video file produced.

Right now, it **does** interrupt with EOF replaced, and it does also pull the file, but the pulled file is *always* corrupted.

Any ideas?

I tried adding `wait` 's and using various interrupt types to replace the EOF signal but to no avail.

This produces identical results; corrupted video file.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x; clear

fileName="rec.$$.mp4"

record(){
    adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/$fileName & childPID=$!

    read -n 1 -s -r -p ''
    kill "$childPID"
    wait "$childPID"
}

extract(){
    adb pull sdcard/$fileName
}

record | wait && extract; exit
```

Replacing the `kill` command with `exit` produces identical results as well.

Comment: So I guess you'll want to just `kill` the background process and `wait` for it to complete, before downloading the file.

Comment: @KamilCuk, unfortunately, that did not work either. Using `exit` and `kill` to interrupt the `screenrecord` subprocess both corrupt the output of the `screenrecord` command, as it is expected the ctrl-D (EOF) signal.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the character, kill the background process and wait for it to finish

```
fileName="rec.$$.mp4"
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/"$fileName" &
childpid=$!
read -n 1 -s -r -p '' endRec
kill "$childpid"
wait "$childpid"
adb pull /sdcard/"$fileName"
```

Rather then using `abd pull`, just pipe the screenrecord to your file and save it on the fly.

```
fileName="rec.$$.mp4"
adb shell screenrecord - > "$fileName" &
childpid=$!
read -n 1 -s -r -p '' endRec
kill "$childpid"
wait "$childpid"
```

> I have verified that manually entering the screenrecord command and using the EOF signal to interrupt the screenrecord command,

Create a fifo and send it.

```
tmpd=$(mktemp -d)
fifo="$tmpd/fifo"
mkfifo "$fifo"
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/"$fileName" < "$fifo" &
childpid=$!
read -n 1 -s -r -p '' endRec
echo -e '\04' > "$fifo"
wait "$childpid"
rm -r "$tmpd" # cleanup
adb pull /sdcard/"$fileName"
```

Alternatively a bash coprocess could be good here.

Comment: piping, unfortunately, is not universally compatible enough for use in the studio I work at. adb pull has permissions to write to the file system but not piping directly from the device's shell. the device won't have permissions on the computer's file system by default and I don't want to change that.

Adding the kill and wait produces the same output.

p.s. I have verified that manually entering the screenrecord command and using the EOF signal to interrupt the screenrecord command, then using ADB pull, that that works.

I think the issue here is in not using an EOF Signal for interrupt

Comment: `the EOF signal` what is an "EOF signal"? How do you use it? If you use "ctrl+c" it sends SIGINT signal. `the device won't have permissions on the computer's file system` - I do not really understand that, it looks like you want `| sudo tee "$fileName" >/dev/null`

Comment: this script includes many network features, and for security, this script cannot run any commands with root privileges.

For EOF: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110248/398104

Comment: Edited. Just open any interprocess communication with another process and send to it you want to end. For example a fifo. The [documentation for abd shell screenrecord](https://adbshell.com/commands/adb-shell-screenrecord) states: `Recording continues until Ctrl-C is hit or the time limit is reached`, it doesn't mention EOT character. I think also try `kill -s SIGINT "$childpid"`, could be SIGTERM is not handled well.

Answer (score 1):

Success! After much trial and error, I figured out a method to send `eof` to the screenrecord function running on the device's shell!

The solution was to trap traditional signals, and have the script send `adb shell echo \04` whenever the exitScript function is called (note that is also the function that the most common signals will execute when caught).

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x; clear

fileName="rec.$$.mp4"

# make sure SIGINT always works even in presence of infinite loops
exitScript() {
    trap - SIGINT SIGTERM SIGTERM SIGSTOP # clear the trap
    adb shell echo \04; extract; exit
}; trap exitScript SIGINT SIGTERM SIGSTOP # set trap

record(){   
    adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/$fileName
}

extract(){
    adb pull sdcard/$fileName
}

record && extract
exitScript
```

I also believe that not running `screenrecord` in a subshell might've helped to avoid corrupting the output file.

After making the screenrecord function loop until an interrupt occurs (then extracting in the background for continuous video sequences), and putting everything in a function to plug into my script, I think issue is fully resolved. Thanks for all your help!

```
#!/bin/bash

screenDVR(){
    clear
    read -r -p 'Enter the file path (or just drag the folder itself) of where you want to save the video sequences.. ' savePath
    if [ ! "$savePath" = "" ]; then cd ~; cd "$savePath"; else printf "\nDefaulting to home directory\n"; cd ~; fi

    # remove all files on device containing 'rec.'
    adb -d shell rm -f *"/sdcard/rec."*

    # make sure SIGINT always works even in presence of infinite loops
    exitScript() {
        trap - SIGINT SIGTERM SIGTERM # clear the trap
        tput cnorm
        adb -d shell echo \04; wait

        extract

        # remove all files on device containing 'rec.'
        adb -d shell rm -f *"/sdcard/rec."*; wait
        exit
    }; trap exitScript SIGINT SIGTERM # set trap

    extract(){
        printf "\n%*s\n" $((0)) "Extracting.. $fileName .. to your computer!"
        wait && adb pull sdcard/$fileName || return
    }

    record(){   
        printf "\n\n%*s\n\n" $((0)) "Use CTRL-C to stop the DVR.."
        while true; do
            tStamp="$(date +'%Hh%Mm%Ss')"
            fileName="rec.$tStamp.$$.mp4"

            printf "\n%*s\n\n" $((0)) "Starting new recording: $fileName"
            adb -d shell screenrecord /sdcard/$fileName || adb shell echo \04

            # running extract in a sub-process means the next video doesn't have any time-gap from the last
            wait; extract & continue
        done
    }
    record && wait && exitScript
}

(screenDVR) && printf "\ncontinue main loop\n"; exit
```

Comment: This is really great! thanks for sharing - one thing on my machine (mas osx using bash), is that hitting CTRL-C doesn't exit. it correctly pulls the file, but stays running. if I hit CTRL-C again, it saves another recording